# What is the purpose of the postgresql database when using Heroku with Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite, heroku

I'm starting a new project using Django and hosting it on Heroku. I know that Django comes with a SQLite db ready to use for the application to store all of the app's data.

Heroku requires PostgreSQL - does this mean that my app will have to be configured locally to use this database INSTEAD OF the SQLite db - or does it use both? Is the PostgreSQL db just something that the Heroku app needs to work or do you actually need this to run your Django app in Heroku?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3, which will likely answer your questions.

Comment: Thanks! It didn't seem straightforward so this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Also SQLite is not production ready and should never be used in a live environment

Answer (score 0):

Found answer on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3. Heroku uses/prefers postgres and not sqlite.